# How to prove premise-conclusion statements with rules of inference?

Tags: logic

I have a question here:

2. For each of the premise-conclusion pairs below, give a valid step-by-step argument (proof)
   along with the name of the inference rule used in each step. For examples, see pages 73
   and 74 in textbook.

First question:

(a) Premise: {¬p ∨ q → r, s ∨ ¬q, ¬t, p → t, ¬p ∧ r → ¬s}, conclusion: ¬q.

I only got this far:

¬p v ¬q v r

I have absolutely no idea what to do next. If someone could give me some general tips to solve this problem and others like it it would be great. I know, i only did one step..

Help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the simplest atoms and working down:

- The simplset atom is $\neg t$. What does that give me? Where does $t$ appear? Oh look! From $\neg t$ and $p\implies t$, you have $\neg p$
- Ok, now I have $\neg p$ as well as $\neg t$. Where does $p$ appear? Oh! From $\neg p \lor q\to r$, I now have $r$, since $\neg p\lor q$ is true!.
- Now, where do $p$ and $r$ appear? Oh, in the last premise! $\neg p \land r\to \neg s$ gives me $\neg s$, since I know $\neg p\land r$ is true!

Starting from the conclusion and working up:

- Where does $s$ appear as a conclusion? Ok, it appears either in $s\lor \neg q$ or it appears in $\neg p \land r\to \neg s$. Well, my intuition tells me that the second one looks more promising, since I don's see how I could disprove $\neg q$.
- So, how can I prove $\neg p \land r$? Well, I need to prove both $r$ and $\neg p$. Let's start with $r$ first.

  - I can prove $r$ if I prove $\neg p \lor q$, since $\neg p \lor q \to r$. Oh, but I have to prove $\neg p$ anyway, so as long as I can prove $\neg p$, I'm done!
  - There is no $\neg p$ anywhere to prove. Is this a problem? Well, no, since $p\to t$ is the same as $\neg t\to \neg p$. OK, so I only need to prove $\neg t$. How can I prove that? Oh! I don't have to ! It's an axiom! Well, job done.

Comment: Why do we need to look at $\neg$$t$? doesnt  p⟹t mean $\neg$$p$ anyway? I'm confused on this..  Ok since $\neg$$p$ is true, then $\neg$$p$ v $q$ has to be true. I'm with you so far. I'm getting confused when you say that you have $r$ since $TRUE$$\rightarrow$$r$

Comment: @AjeetKljh Certainly not. For example, if $p=\text{water is wet}$, and $t=\text{the earth is round}$, then the statement $p\to t$ is true, but the statement $\neg p$ is not true.

Comment: @AjeetKljh If $A\to B$ is true and $A$ is true, then $B$ is true. This rule of inference is called **modus ponens**.

Comment: In my book it says modus tollens is $\neg$$q$ | $p$$\rightarrow$$q$ | therefore $\neg$$p$. That implies $\neg$$p$ is true?

Comment: Yes, you prove $\neg p$ by using modus tollens. Modus tollens says that if $A\to B$ is true and if $\neg B$ is true, then $\neg A$ is true. In your case, $p\to t$ is true and $\neg t$ is true, so $\neg p$ is also true.

Comment: Alright so when it says $\therefore$ q for example, that means $q$ is true? (In the list of inference rules).

Comment: @AjeetKljh That's what an inference rule is, yes. It is a rule that says "if these things are true, then these other things are also true".

Comment: Okay this is starting to make sense. I hope im right here. Now that we know $\neg$$p$ is true, that means $\neg$$p$ v $q$   is    $TRUE$. $TRUE$ v $q$ $\rightarrow$ $r$    =    $TRUE$ $\rightarrow$ $r$. Using modus ponens, $r$ is true. Since I have both $\neg$$p$ and $r$, I can get $\neg$$s$ from the last premise where $\neg$$p$ $\land$ $r$ $\rightarrow$ $\neg$$s$. Using modus ponens, $\neg$$s$ is $TRUE$.  Now I can get $s$ from $s$ v $\neg$$q$, and $s$ is false, so $FALSE$ v $\neg$$q$, from the domination law, is $\neg$$q$.

Comment: @AjeetKljh Correct. You have now also proven that $\neg q$ is true, which is more than what your original question asks for.

Comment: why is $\neg$$q$ false?

Comment: @AjeetKljh A typo. I meant to write $\neg q$ is *true*.

Comment: how do you know the value of $\neg$$q$ though

Comment: @AjeetKljh In general, if $A\lor B$ is true, and $\neg A$ is true, then $B$ is true. This rule of inference is called **Disjunctive Syllogism**. In your case, since $s\lor \neg q$ is true, and $\neg s$ is false, then $\neg q$ is true.

Comment: thanks so much btw. i have an other one if you dont mind helping.. im stuck on $t$$\rightarrow$$s$. I started with $\neg$$w$ and worked from there..  Premise: {¬p → r ∧ ¬s, t → s, u → ¬p, ¬w, u ∨ w}, conclusion: ¬t ∨ w. since $r$ is true, using Simplification ($p$$\land$$q$$\therefore$$q$), that means $\neg$$s$ is $true$. $t$$\rightarrow$$s$ is $t$$\rightarrow$$FALSE$.. thats as far as i got

Comment: @AjeetKljh I suggest you ask it in another question, and accept my answer in this one.

Comment: If I have $\forall$$x$ or $\exists$$x$ can i still use the same rules of inference to prove?

Comment: @AjeetKljh You then have additional rules.

Comment: thank you very much for the help. i have another one im stuck with now :S . i posted another question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477371/how-to-prove-arguments-with-rules-of-inference . i did the first step, don't know what to use from there.