# How to prove arguments with rules of inference?

Tags: logic

I have the following argument:

-∀x(P(x) ∨ Q(x))

∀x(¬P(x) ∧ Q(x)) → R(x)

___________________.

∴ ∀x(¬R(x) → P(x))

I don't want the answer. I just need some general tips to get there. I know I can use Universal Instantiation on the two arguments to remove $\forall$$x$, but that's about it. I can't see any other rules I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the second sentence as:
$$\forall x (\neg R(x) \to \neg(\neg P(x) \wedge Q(x)))$$
by taking the contrapositive of the inner formula. That in turn is equivalent to:
$$\forall x (\neg R(x) \to P(x) \vee \neg Q(x))$$
(Here, we get rid of one pair of parentheses by using the convention that $\vee, \wedge$ bind more tightly than $\to$).
So temporarily instantiate the universally quantified x:
$$ (\neg R(a) \to P(a) \vee \neg Q(a))$$.
Suppose $$\neg R(a) \tag{not-R(a)}$$
Then:
$$ P(a) \vee \neg Q(a) \tag{PnotQ}$$
Instantiating the first sentence $\forall x (P(x) \vee Q(x))$ with $a$ gives:
$$P(a) \vee Q(a) \tag{PQ}$$
From (PnotQ) and (PQ) you can conclude:
$$P(a)$$
Here's why:  (PnotQ) is equivalent to $Q(a) \to P(a)$, and (PQ) is equivalent to $\neg Q(a) \to P(a)$. From these, we can conclude $Q(a) \vee \neg Q(a) \to P(a)$. But of course $Q(a) \vee \neg Q(a)$ is provable, so by *modus ponens*, $P(a)$.

Discharging the assumption (not-R(a)) gives:
$$\neg R(a) \to P(a)$$
Finally, $a$ was just temporary, so we can eliminate it and universally quantify:
$$ \forall x(\neg R(x) \to P(x))$$

Comment: I added a bit to explain what you asked about in your comment, which has now disappeared... so perhaps I didn't have to.

Comment: How did you conclude with P(a)?

Comment: See the "Here's why:" paragraph -- still not clear?

Comment: sorry i added that comment just as you edited the post. im confused about the $Q(a) \rightarrow P(a)$ part. the rest makes sense

Comment: But that's just instantiating the first of your two hypotheses.

Comment: It doesn't say $Q(a) \rightarrow P(a)$ anywhere though

Comment: Laws of (classical) logic: $A \to B$ is equivalent to $\neg A \vee B$; $\neg \neg A$ is equivalent to $A$.

Comment: oh. right yes. thank you

Comment: was the last step there proved by contrapositive? Since we got $P(a)$ (which is true), we can say that the second statement (where $\neg P(a) \land Q(a)$ is false. In other words, $\neg P(a)$ (By simplification). Therefore, since $\neg P(a) \rightarrow R(a)$, we can use the contrapositive to get $\neg R(a) \rightarrow P(a)$

Comment: I don't understand: $\neg P(a) \wedge Q(a)$ is the negation of (PnotQ), and certainly that is never "proved". From $A \to B$ and $\neg A \to B$ you can conclude $B$.

Answer (score 0):

In the second assumption you write that P(x) and Q(x) can't occur so by contraopistion of the second assumption combining with the first you the required result.